# Define a new column based on preferences in one set of columns, and available resources in another

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with many columns, of which 7 are relevant here.

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Shipment ID':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'Pref 1':['UPS','DHL','DHL','ARA','USPS','FED'],'Pref 2':['DHL','','FED','FED','UPS','USPS'],'Pref 3':['FED','','','DHL','ARA',''],'BudgetUPS':[NaN,'No','Yes',NaN,'No','Yes'],'BudgetUSPS':['Yes','Yes','Yes',NaN,'Yes','No'],'BudgetFED':['No','Yes',NaN,'Yes','Yes','No'],'BudgetARA':['Yes',NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,'Yes'],'BudgetDHL':['No','Yes','Yes',NaN,'Yes','Yes']})
```

The data here represents the top 3 customer preferences for a shipping agent for each of the shipments being generated by an e-commerce site. The Budget columns specify whether the budget for the corresponding shipping agent is available, not available, or unknown (due to query failure).

What I need to generate is a column that picks up the top two (or one, or none) of the preferences for each shipment ID and create entries (column name: Prefnbudget) like "FED UPS", "USPS", "DHL ARA", "None" for each shipment. The purpose of this step is to a) detect if a shipment can be processed with customer preference, and the budget constraint (to prevent deadlocks), b) query the customer with a confirmation.

I would like to make the answer as pythonic as possible. It is certainly easy to do this in a loop over a list ['DHL','UPS','USPS','ARA','FED'], etc. but I want something that is more vectorized, and pithily compact.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your dataframe. Below is one way to implement your task:

```
# this dictionary maps column name to its index (column count) in the dataframe
dictIndexToCol = {col_name: i for i, col_name in enumerate(df1.columns)}

def getPref(row, dictIdxToCol=dictIndexToCol):
    """ This function takes the preferences and checks whether Budget value is Yes """
    pref1 = row[1]
    pref2 = row[2]
    pref3 = row[3]

    pref_budget = " "
    if len(pref1) > 0:
        if row[dictIdxToCol[f"Budget{pref1}"]] == "Yes":
            pref_budget += pref1 + " "

    if len(pref2) > 0:            
        if row[dictIdxToCol[f"Budget{pref2}"]] == "Yes":
            pref_budget += pref2 + " "

    if len(pref3) > 0:             
        if row[dictIdxToCol[f"Budget{pref3}"]] == "Yes":
            pref_budget += pref3

    return pref_budget

df1["Prefnbudget"] = df1.apply(lambda row: getPref(row), axis=1)
```